# android application

Tags: android, html

i am a beginner in android.now i am familiar with layout concept.i can add different layer in android.Now i want to know how can i divide the emulator into two or more parts.just like < frameset > in html.i want to perform edit or refresh one part, without disturbing other part.Somebody told me that it is done by multilayer concept.But i didn't see any multilayer concept in anywhere .when i am trying to search " multilayer concept in android", it always lead to layout concept. So somebody told me how can i perform this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with **Sheikh Aman's** answer.

But if you look at the Android 3.0 Honeycomb features then there are some interesting features. Like contacts application has a two pane user interface.

Also you can breaks your application Activities into the subcomponents (fragments). And by combining them you can create a rich UI with the multiple panes.

Like this one:

[image: Android 3.0 contacts App with multiple pane]

However sounds like it's only for the Tablets but hope it's what you want to know like as Frameset's in HTML.

See more here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html#ui

Comment: thank you vikas for your answer...now can you tell me how you place the picture in the answer

Comment: @khan: you can insert picture in both question and answer. See this : [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

I too haven't found any multi-layer concept yet LoL

Its about a god mix of Layouts only

Comment: My pleasure.. you can have a horizontal line separating your views.

Comment: But we can refresh each view in our main layout independently . :-D